# How to find correlation between some columns using corrplot function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I have a dataset containing 12 columns. I wanted to plot correlation between some of the columns.
when I use corrplot() , it plots 12x12 which makes it hard to visualize it.

this is the function I used and it's showing the whole dataset correlation

```
 corrplot(cor(demo.data), addCoef.col = "grey")
```

and it shows this

[carrplot()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVq5K.png)

any help to make it for just some columns?

Comment: Maybe you can separate the columns which you want to correlate and plot it from there. Can you show us some of your dataset?

Comment: Try `corrplot(cor(demo.data[, 1:6]), addCoef.col = "grey")` to get just the first six columns or `corrplot(cor(demo.data[, c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)]), addCoef.col = "grey")` to get the odd columns.